# Firestore Security Rules With User Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

firestore is not synced with user authentication, keep returning all data for all the users. The   firestore rules I have been writing are this but it keeps on returning errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFv5r.png

This useEffect is used to return data when the user signs in but

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDP2Z.png

it keeps giving error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Hv0.png

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? What does not synced with user auth mean? You are not using firebase auth? Also your rules you have written would need you to have firebase auth and the task id would need to be the same as the users auth id from firebase auth

Comment: [classified](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10876543/classified) I'm using firebase auth (email and password) and the error is Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. I have checked multiple resources all tends to give the same exact rule. I want a user to have their own data separate from other users

Comment: 1) Rules on their own don't do anything. They only become active once you run code against them. Please edit your question (there's an `edit` link right under it) to include the code that doesn't work as you expect it to. Also show in the code how it actually meets the requirements of your rules, i.e. by logging the current user just before calling the database. ---

Comment: 2) Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.